# WebSphere server not taking the new changes in the EAR

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, deployment, websphere, rad

Steps followed

1. deployed the application through RAD 8.5 which is built by ant(WebSphere server 7)
2. maven migration has been done for that project
3. then I have deployed the application which is built by maven, But I am unable to see the JSP changes in the UI.
4. some how old ear not replaced with new ear.
5. I have also uninstalled the application through WAS administrative console and deployed the new ear. Still not able to deploy new ear.

Can you anyone tell? why changes are not reflected.

Is it possible to delete some temp/ installed directory manually?

Comment: Is this a JSF project?

Comment: plain jsp and servlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just delete and created the new profile. Now it is getting deployed.

Answer (score 1):

If you're deploying through RAD,  and the server properties are set to "run with resources in workspace", then in my experience, sometimes things will not be propagated to the server.  You can change the setting to "run with resources on server" which is more like a regular app install.  It takes a little longer.

Also mixing console deploys and deploys through RAD can leave RAD in a confused state, it's better to do exclusively one or the other while RAD is attached to the server.

Answer (score 0):

There can be the following reasons causing this issue.

1. The project stage "PRODUCTION" in the web.xml prevents publishing the new changes to the application, so change it to development as follows.

   ```
   <context-param>
       <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
       <param-value>Development</param-value>
   </context-param>
   ```
2. Another reason might be the old .class files that are there in the /bin folder of the project, delete them and do a clean build.

Comment: nope i didn't use this context param also there is no bin dir